# Site stoppped working on http after adding ssl/https

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, windows-server-2012-r2, https

My site, lets say abc.com was working on http and not on https. After adding these lines to httpd.conf,

```
ServerName abc.com
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
Listen 443
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile C:/MyPath/MyCertcer
SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/MyPath/MyKey.key
SSLCACertificateFile C:/MyPath/MyCAA.crt
```

My site started to work on https but stopped on http. These settings are not inside Virtual-Host or Directory. I am getting,

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12 Server at abc.com Port 443
```

In my conf at top I also have,

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple httpd.conf configurations will do. For example:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName abc.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName abc.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile C:/MyPath/MyCert.cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/MyPath/MyKey.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: NameVirtualHost is deprecated (and ignored) in 2.4

Comment: @ezra-s what should I add then.

Comment: @user960567 - Just delete the two `NameVirtualHost` lines... I'm an old hack :-).

Answer (score 2):

When you already have a certificate and SSL running you can just redirect all requests to the secure SSL site:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName example.com
   DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile C:/MyPath/MyCertcer
   SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/MyPath/MyKey.key
   SSLCACertificateFile C:/MyPath/MyCAA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

See more on https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL